# 400 ICAP Error for reqmod message

Tags: squid

I am getting the following error... "Error 400 Bad Request". for ICAP Reqmod message. Here's a snippet of the example ICAP client code..

```
request = "GET http://www.foobar.com HTTP/1.1\n\n";
output.println("REQMOD icap://" + server + ":" + "1344" + "/"+ "REQMOD" + " " + "1.0" +"\r");
output.println("Host:" + server + ":" + port + "\")
output.println("Encapsulated: req-hdr=0, null-body=" + length);
output.println("Preview: 0\r");
output.println("Allow: 204\r");

output.println("\r");
output.print(request);
output.println("\r");
```

Appreciate any help on this...this is a very simple ICAP client and i use the same format for sending ICAP options message and that works...for some reason REQMOD is getting rejected as bad request...

Comment: Did you get any answer in the ICAP forum so far? I'm interested myself.

Comment: nope didn't get any help there too.

Answer (score 0):

```
output.println("REQMOD icap://" + server + ":" + "1344" + "/"+ "REQMOD" + " " + "1.0" +"\r");
```

I guess what you wanted to specify was
REQMOD icap://serverip:1344/ ICAP/1.0 instead of specifying a second REQMOD

Answer (score 0):

there are some carriage return missing. that's all.

Comment: Please expand your answer and provide the modified code from the question to make it a really good answer.